# How do I set the section and subsection fonts to Times New Roman as well as section font to be Times New Roman

Tags: fonts

How do I set the section and the subsection font to Times New Roman. I have done every trick in the book. But nothing works.

Comment: It would help if you showed us at least one of your tries. `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` should work, or, with LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX, `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Times New Roman}`.

Comment: I believe, you should also clearify what you actually mean by (sub)section fonts: The titles only or the running text too?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It is not good typography to have too many fonts in your document. So the best would be to switch to TNR or a TNR-look-alike as your default roman family for the whole document using one of the approaches suggested by Paul Gessler or something similar. (There are a lot of Times/TNR clones to choose from.) It would not be wise, for example, to make your headings TNR while typesetting the remainder in a different serif font, and sans is not suitable for running text either.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might just want to change the font of the entire document, as others have suggested.

But if you only want to change the font of the section and subsection headings, the `memoir` class gives you easy access to format the headings. You can use the `fontspec` package to create a font-switching command that you then apply to the headings using `memoir`'s built-in style commands. (Memoir's excellent manual is accessible by entering "texdoc memoir" at the terminal.)

This solution only works with `LuaLaTeX` or `XeTeX`.

This example contrasts the Times headings with dummy paragraph text, set in the default Computer/Latin Modern font.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% Create a command to switch the font to Times for headings
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\headingfont}{Times New Roman}

% Create headings that use this command
\makeheadstyles{myheadings}{%
\setsecheadstyle{\headingfont\bfseries} 
\setsubsecheadstyle{\headingfont\itshape}
}
% \bfseries and \itshape are just examples; 
% you could add any style or font commands here, 
% as described in the memoir handbook

 % Select your custom headings for the document
\headstyles{myheadings} 

% Dummy paragraph text which will be displayed in default Computer Modern
\usepackage{lipsum}

%***************
\begin{document}

\section{Section Heading in Times}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Subsection Also in Times}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?